# Почему ругается на то что переменная не инициалищированна, когда она инициализированна?

Tags: swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему ругается на то что переменная не инициализированна, когда она инициализированна, в случае когда я использую переменную в одном случае( в конструкции при выполнении условия, я присваиваю переменной значение). Но при этом в другом случае ( когда я просто присваиваю ей значение) не ругается.

Comment: Видимо компилятор свифта ещё не настолько умный, что бы проанализировать весь код и понять, что условие выполняется всегда (а может он что то знает, чего не знаем мы и условие может вдруг оказаться  ложным), поэтому и ругается.

Comment: Приводите подобный код и сообщения текстом, а не гигантскими скриншотами, плиз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на сообщение : "variable **used before** being initialized", то есть нужно, чтобы инициализация была осуществлена до момента использования переменной.

В Вашем первом примере из комментариев переменная **y** не используется, поэтому то, что она (пока) не инициализирована, не принципиально.

Во втором примере из комментариев, ситуация аналогично описанной в изначальном вопросе: есть вероятность, что переменная **kind1** не будет инициализирована (например, если условие if не будет выполнено, или если num окажется пустым), поэтому попытка использования этой переменной в **print(kind1,largest)** вызывает ту же ошибку.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, наконец то понял!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что если Вы указали `non-optional` тип, то он обязательно должен быть инициализирован. В Вашем случае есть вероятность, что `y` может быть не инициализирован из-за `if`. Ему не важно значение сравниваемых переменных.

Если Вы хотите чтобы запустился Ваш пример с `if`, замените

```
var y: String
```

на

```
var y: String?
```

Либо добавьте `else`:

```
else {
    y = "Magic"
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Но тогда почему возможна такая конструкция, тут переменная не инициализируется. Я правильно понял что если не опцианалтный тип переменной то она обязательно должна быть инициализированна в течении программы? var a = 1
var b = 2
var x = "ashdj"
var y: String
print(x)

Comment: let interestingNumbers = 
[
 "Prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13],
 "Fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8],
 "Square": [1,4,9,16,25],
]
var largest = 0
var kind1: String
for (kind, num) in interestingNumbers
 {
  for number1 in num
   {if number1>largest{largest=number1
kind1=kind}}
 }
print(kind1,largest) И почему тут тоже выдает такую же ошибку? Заранее спасибо

Comment: @ВиталийПавловичКовалев в принципе, во втором ответе на комментарии ответили. А если в общем по случаям - смотрите на комментрий к ошибке, там подробно расписана проблема.

Comment: И Вам огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Можно lazy property использовать

```
lazy var y: String = {
return "some string" //какая-та логика
}()
```